# Why cant I rotate my imageview with one finger Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesmoved

So Im making a DJ app and I have this turntable that I would like to spin to the left and right using touch. I got it to move when a song is being played but not sure how to get it to spin using touch.

EDIT*******
I got it to work but I need to rotate the imageview using one finger instead of two. How would I get that to work? Thank you

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {

    var angle: CGFloat = 0
    var rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rotate(_:)))
        self.leftTurnTable.addGestureRecognizer(self.rotate)
    }

    func rotate(r:UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

        self.leftTurnTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle+r.rotation)

        if r.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            self.angle += r.rotation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the "spin" code out a method so that both `playButton` and your touch handler can call it.

Comment: okay so I called the spin code in the touchesMoved but it doesnt let me turn the turntable to the left or right. It stops spinning when I touch anywhere in the view and starts spinning when I let go.

Comment: Yes so I wanted my image view which is a turntable to be able to move 360 like an actual turntable. I could spin to the left and right and when there is no touch it stops spinning.

Comment: Do you get what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No. Do you want to drag it to turn it, like a doorknob, or do you want to fling it to set it spinning and have it slow down gradually, like a top?

Comment: @coding22 you should take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/

Comment: Like a doorknob? Then see the explanation in my free online book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_custom_controls You can easily adapt that.

Comment: @LeoDabus Hey can you take a look at my code I got it to work but I would like to use only one finger to rotate it instead of two. How would I do that?

Comment: @coding22 i have no idea. I always do it using the rotation gesture.

Comment: @LeoDabus damm im so close.

Comment: You can try swap gesture recognizer for single finger gestures

Comment: got it to work using touchesMoved instead. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


     let touch = touches.first
    if touch!.view === leftTurnTable {
        let position = touch!.locationInView(self.view)
        let target = leftTurnTable.center
        let angle = atan2(target.y-position.y, target.x-position.x)
        leftTurnTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    }
}
```